# Selenium Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, content-security-policy

I am trying to create a small selenium script in python which loops through one of my organization's website's urls available in csv.

But the website needs SAML login before it access any URL. So, my selenium script first logs into the site then tries to opens the urls from csv.

SAML login takes username and password from profile site and redirects back to origin site upon successful login. But after typing username and password, when clicking "login" button, website throws exception "some error occured".

When I open developer console of Chrome, I see this exception "Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: 'unsafe-eval'". Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I tried with Chrome Driver as well as Firefox Driver, but getting same kind of exception.